# How do I know what functions are run in Generic Views?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django and scratching my head with the following question
how do I know which function is run in specific processes?
for example in below view, retrieve function is executed. I flipped the documentation, however, could not find anything named retrieve to overwrite

```
class ProfileRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, username, *args, **kwargs):
        print("hey yo i am running 01")
        try:
            profile = Profile.objects.select_related('user').get(
                user__username=username
            )
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            raise

        serializer = self.serializer_class(profile)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Hello, I am not sure to understand your question. Retrieve is executed anytime you send a GET request to an URL for a single object, in your case being identified by the username attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the generic views in Django Rest Framework are made by inheriting from various mixins. It is also documented which mixin a view is inheriting from. For example the [documentation for `RetrieveAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview) which you use is as follows:

> Used for read-only endpoints to represent a single model instance.
>
> Provides a `get` method handler.
>
> Extends:
> [GenericAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview),
> [RetrieveModelMixin](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrievemodelmixin)

So you can override `get` here if needed (it actually calls the `retrieve` method here). If you further follow the link for `RetrieveModelMixin` you will see that it's documentation has this line:

> Provides a `.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)` method, that implements
> returning an existing model instance in a response.

Here we can see it mentions that it provides a `retrieve` method. So you just need to check the documentation for the super classes for a respective class if you want to know what method is used by it.

> **Note**: If all else fails when searching the documentation consider simply looking at it's the source code on GitHub or in your own IDE.
> ;)

Comment: thank you very much for ur answer. I will dive to the super class in this case

Answer (score 0):

According to DRF documentation, there is a default mapping the views and the router:

- `list` is for `GET` on a list of objects, like `/users/`
- `retrieve` is for `GET` on a single object, like `/users/3/`
- `create` is for `POST` on a non-detailed endpoint, like `/users/`
- `update` is for `PUT` on a detailed endpoint, like `/users/3/`
- `partial_update` is for `PATCH` on a detailed endpoint, like `/users/3/`
- `destroy` is for `DELETE` on a detailed endpoint, like `/users/3/`

Those are the expected/standard mappings within DRF views and viewsets

You can view some examples here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins